# How can I make multiple images overlap and scroll together

Tags: html, css

The mobile application has a page that shows a room with a few fix features and several that can be conditionally displayed. The display (portrait mode only) is large enough that scrolling is not required.

Now, I want to have a similar display except that there are several row of controls that affect which items are displayed. The number of controls will vary. All of the images (*.svg) are 360 x 242 pixels.

How can I make all of the images overlap, even when scrolling?
[image: arrow png]

```
﻿<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Scroll Room</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="merged_mobile.min.css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content_view">
        <!-- Channel Mapping -->
        <div class="page">
            <div class="page_name">
                <p>Room View</p>
            </div>
            <div class="ul_wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <button id="height_1" class="nav-side-menu-item">
                            <span>Option 1</span>
                            <img src="arrow.png" />
                            <span></span>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button id="height_2" class="nav-side-menu-item">
                            <span>Option 2</span>
                            <img src="arrow.png" />
                            <span></span>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="nav-side-menu-item-divider">Divider</div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button id="option_a" class="nav-side-menu-item">
                            <span>Alpha</span>
                            <img src="arrow.png" />
                            <span></span>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button id="option_b" class="nav-side-menu-item">
                            <span>Beta</span>
                            <img src="arrow.png" />
                            <span></span>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="nav-side-menu-item-divider">Room Diagram</div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="moving_room">
                            <img class="room_base_img" src="background.svg" alt="room background">
                            <img class="room_diagram_img" src="walls_transparent.svg" alt="transparent walls">
                            <img class="room_diagram_img" src="table.svg" alt="table">
                            <img class="room_diagram_img" src="couch.svg" alt="couch">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

merged_mobile.min.css

```
:root{
--row-height: 67px;
--highlight-color: #077bff;
--tertiary-background-color: #404040;
--primary-font-color: white;
--secondary-font-color: #ccc;
--header-color: #fff;
}

/* Thin */
@font-face {
font-family: "SF Display Thin";
font-display: block;
src: url("../fonts/SF_Pro_Display_Thin.woff2");
}

/* Regular */
@font-face {
font-family: "SF Display Regular";
font-display: block;
src: url("../fonts/SF_Pro_Display_Regular.woff2");
}

html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
min-width: 300px;
}

body{
font-family: 'SF Display Regular', sans-serif;
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
color: white;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
caret-color: orange;
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
-moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
-ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+/Edge */
user-select: none;
}

p {
margin: 0;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: none;
outline-style: none;
}

li {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

button {
height: 36px;
width: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-weight: 200;


}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
background-color: #404040;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar
{
width: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
background: dimgray;
}

.content_view {
overflow-x: hidden;
height: 100%;
}

#room_diagram_button{
background-color: red;
}
#room_diagram_button img{
width: 25px;
float: right;
margin-top: 22px;
padding-right: 10px;
}

.room_diagram {
position: relative;
}

.room_base_img {
height: 290px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
}
.room_diagram_img {
height: 290px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
}
.room_diagram_img.speaker {
display: none;
}
.moving_room {
    height: 290px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    width: 100%;
    /*left: 0;*/
}

.nav-side-menu-item {
color: var(--primary-font-color);
font-size: 20px;
height: var(--row-height);
background-color: transparent;
border: none;
}
.nav-side-menu-item span:first-child{
float: left;
height: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
width: calc(100% - 150px);
text-align: left;
margin-left: 15px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
line-height: var(--row-height);
}

.nav-side-menu-item span:nth-child(2), .nav-side-menu-item span:nth-child(3) {
font-size: 14px;
padding-right: 10px;
float:right;
width: 90px;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: transparent;
text-align: right;

height: var(--row-height);
line-height: var(--row-height);
}
.nav-side-menu-item img{
width: 22px;
height: 22px;
float: right;
margin-top: 22px;
padding-right: 10px;
}

.nav-side-menu-item-divider {
text-decoration: none;
color: var(--primary-font-color);
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
line-height: normal;
background-color: dimgray;
cursor: auto;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.page {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
}

.page_name{
position: relative;
background: #404040;
height: 50px;

}
.page_name p{
font-size: 24px;
line-height:50px;
height: 50px;
white-space: nowrap;
text-align: center;
min-width: 320px;
}

.back_button img{
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
}

.back_button{
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
position: absolute;
border: none;
outline-style: none;
background-color: var(--header-color);
}

.page_contents{
padding: 15px;
}

.ul_wrapper {
height: -moz-calc(100% - 50px);
height: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
height: calc(100% - 50px);
display: block;
overflow: auto;
}
.ul_wrapper li {
line-height: 0;
border-bottom: 1px white solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added id attributes so that I could manipulate the controls with jQuery.

```
<li>
    <div id="moving_room">
        <img class="room_base_img" id="roombg" src="background.svg" alt="room background">
        <img class="room_moveable_img" id="roomwalls" src="walls_transparent.svg" alt="transparent walls">
        <img class="room_moveable_img" id="roomt" src="table.svg" alt="table">
        <img class="room_moveable_img" id="roomc" src="couch.svg" alt="couch">
    </div>
</li>
```

And some new styles.

```
.room_base_img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.room_moveable_img {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I determined the height of the top image and applied it to the images below it.

```
var imght = $("#roombg").height();
$("#roomwalls").attr("style", "top: _px".stuffus(0 - imght));
$("#roomt").attr("style", "top: _px".stuffus(0 - 2 * imght));
$("#roomc").attr("style", "top: _px".stuffus(0 - 3 * imght));
```

The last image had to be scrolled 6000px but it works.